# How to find duplicate entry in Solidity array

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm writing a function that is supposed to receive an array of uint's and I want to make a requirement that none of the elements in the array be the same *and* that all of the elements in the array be part of the pre-selected elements to belong in an array. So far I have:

```
    function vote(uint[] memory proposals) external
    {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote.");
        require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
        mapping(uint => bool) duplicateVotes;
        require(!duplicateVotes, "Cannot vote for a proposal more than once.");
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposals;

        proposals[proposals].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }
```

But I get an error:

```
The data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.
```

But I think this error is just a symptom of a larger problem. Can anyone help me figure out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I think u want to achieve that same person does not vote twice but the way you are doing is computationally expensive and this will cost too much gas. Instead, crate a mapping to keep track if voter has voted before:

```
 mapping(address=>bool) peopleWhoVoted;
```

also you want to keep array of voters

```
 address[] public listOfVoters;
```

So in your vote function, make sure that caller of this function-msg.sender is not in the `peopleWhoVoted` mapping

```
    function vote(pass argument) public {
       // msg.sender is globally available, it is function caller
       require(!peopleWhoVoted[msg.sender],"this caller already voted")
       // now u are sure that this caller did not vote before
       // so u can add the function caller to the array
       listOfVoters.push(msg.sender)
   }
```

Comment: You also need to call `peopleWhoVoted[msg.sender] = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract findDupli {
uint[] public arr = [2,3,4,8,1,7,8];

```
function funFind() public view returns(uint) {
    uint temp;
    for(uint i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp = arr[i];
        for(uint j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if((j != i) && (temp == arr[j])) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}